# Javascript Getting a form element value with localStorage returns null

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store the value of a form element on local storage and display it on another HTML page but when I try to get it from the local storage null is displayed.
This is index.html.

```
<body>
    <form id="form" action="processed.html" onsubmit="submit();"method="get">
         <textarea name="comments" id="a1"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" value="Order Now">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            localStorage.setItem("a2", document.getElementById("a1").value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

This is processed.html

```
<body>
    <div id="answer">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(localStorage.getItem("a2"));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: does the `document.getElementById('a1').value` get the value correctly. If not try using `innerHTML` instead of value

Comment: I tried with innerHTML but it still returns null

Answer (score 0):

just try this..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function submit() {
 var value=document.getElementById("a1").value; 
 localStorage.a2=value;
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, trying to get a jsfiddle for this.

*update

This fiddle is working:
https://jsfiddle.net/dxzL5qoe/

```
function submit() {
    let val = document.getElementById("a1").value;
    localStorage.setItem("a2", val);
    document.querySelector(".output").textContent = `saved ${val} to local storage`;
}

function getLocalstorage(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
}

function doStuff() {
    let storage = getLocalstorage("a2");
    document.querySelector(".output").textContent = `got ${storage} from local storage`;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form id="form" action="processed.html" onsubmit="submit();"method="get">
         <textarea name="comments" id="a1"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" value="Order Now">
    </form>

    <button onclick="doStuff()">Get Local Storage</button>
    <div class="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Test in your code with **console.log(value);** what each value contains or use breakpoints in your code.
Also use inspect page ([F12] / [CTRL + SHIFT + I] -> Application - > Local Storage ) to check if the values is stored in local storage.
I made a quick example for you which worked in my case.

Html:

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
<button onclick="setItem('comment', 'comments');">Submit</button>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

JS:

```
function setItem(key, elementId) {
    var value = document.getElementById(elementId).value;
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    getItem(key);
}
function getItem(key){
    var localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = localStorageValue;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ArnoutPullen/jp9saggb/)